# My ng-view" directive doesn't function the way it is supposed to

Tags: html, angularjs, ngroute, ng-view

I call ng-view, but the program never renders my home.html or cart.html pages. How do I get ng-view to work?

I have tried to use multiple types of references. I have called ng-view in different ways and nothing seems to work.

```
<!--My home.html:-->

<h2> HOME </h2>
<h1>{{message}}</h1>

<!--My cart.html:-->

<h2> CART </h2>
<h1>{{message2}}</h1>
```

Below are my index.html and app.js

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
    when('/cart', {
        templateUrl: 'views/cart.html',
        controller: 'cartController'
    })
    otherwise({
        redirect: '/home'
    });
}]);

myApp.controller('homeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Home Page';
})

myApp.controller('cartController', function($scope){
    $scope.message2 = 'Cart Page';  
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Test Web App</title>

        <meta chrset="utf-8">

        <script src="lib/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/app.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp">
        
        <center><h1>Shopping Cart App</h1></center>
        

        <tr><td class="menu">
            <a href="#/home">Home</a>
            <a href="#/cart">Cart</a>
        </td></tr>
        <dev ng-view></dev>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect that when clicking on either the home link or cart link, ng-view renders their templates.

Comment: The `.config` block has syntax errors. The second `when` method needs to be a dot notation property accessor. Same with the `otherwise` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors. Try putting dots before `when`

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
    .when('/cart', {
        templateUrl: 'views/cart.html',
        controller: 'cartController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirect: '/home'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Oh that did it! Thank you!

Comment: If that worked for you mark it as accepted so other people with the same problem know what to do! @dsafaro